# GLUT Window not responding

Tags: c++, glut

I'm trying to calculate the delta time of my program. In main, I call:

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);

glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);

glutInitWindowSize(250, 250);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);

glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Renderer");

InitGL();

glutDisplayFunc(DrawGLScene);
glutReshapeFunc(ReSizeGLScene);
glutIdleFunc(idle);

glutMainLoop();
```

My idle func:

```
void idle(void)
{
    int time;
    time = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    delta = time - lastTime;
    lastTime = time;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

I have these global variables:

```
int lastTime;
int delta;
float rtri; //Angle for triangle
float rquad; // Angle for quad
```

In the render method, I call:

```
// ...
glRotatef(rtri, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
// ...
rtri += 0.2f * delta;
rquad -= 0.15f * delta;
```

Whith this code, I can't resize the window and if I press the close button, the window isn't responding anymore.

How can I fix this?

Comment: it's a wild guess but I think GLUT (or your code specifically) doesn't handle WM_RESIZE and WM_CLOSE messages.

Comment: but glut is also available on linux and linux has no WM_RESIZE and WM_CLOSE

Comment: doesn't mean anything, there are too many codes which implement different behaviors for different operation systems. for example the whole window creation mechanism in windows in nothing like the one in linux.

Comment: What does your `ReSizeGLScene` function look like?  What do you mean by "the window isn't responding *any more*?"  Were these features working at an earlier time?  If so, what code did you add since they were working?

Comment: Great idea, but in my ReSizeGLScene, I am just correcting the viewport. The Bug is there since I added the idle method (After further tests, I found out, it's not happening without the postGlutRedisplay(); but without this method, it won't redraw automatically.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A friend helped me fixing it.
He wrote a new Sample using double buffering.
If you are interested, you can see the code at [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/37fMbt7b).